# How to rename PrimaryKey and ForeignKey in EF Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I recently rename the column name on my DB. When create a new migration and what I see: EF Core immediately drop column and create a new one. It doesn't make sense to me. Is there any rename foreign key or primary key method?

Answer (score 0):

Use "[HasConstraintName](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hasconstraintname-method)" fluent API like this :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Employees)
        .WithOne(e => e.Company)
        .HasConstraintName("NamFKConstraint");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`MigrationsModelDiffer` is the service class that detects model changes. It "works" by comparing two snapshots of your database model to guess what you changed. Column [renames](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/eb9975bffe2dc17dc9e6ee4111285b9d81f770d1/src/EFCore.Relational/Migrations/Internal/MigrationsModelDiffer.cs#L879) will probably only be detected if nothing else about the column was changed. If you make too many changes at once, then the missing columns will be dropped and new ones added.

If this isn't what you want, you'll need to modify the migration script to specify column renames & other type changes by hand.

```cs
            migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
                name: "old_name",
                table: "table_name",
                newName: "new_name");
```